# Is it safe to use `System.exit()` to stop a java application which has an embed Jetty server?

Tags: java, jetty

I have a java application, which embeds a jetty server to provide http services.

If I visit it via a url:

```
http://localhost:8080/doStop
```

it will stop the jetty server and terminates itself.

I have two options:

```
1. calls `myserver.stop()`, which `myserver` is an instance of `org.mortbay.jetty.Server`, and had set `.setStopAtShutdown(true)`
2. just invoke `System.exit()`
```

I wonder is it safe to just invoke `System.exit()` to stop the whole application?

Comment: If the server provides a way for a clean shutdown, why wouldn't you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use `System.exit(0)`.

But using the stop method from server would be much more cleaner and prevent you of unexpected errors (e.g. still open request).

Answer (score 1):

`System.exit()` is safe unless you have resources to release, half-baked data to persist, or want to ensure the server finishes servicing any open requests before shutting down.

Generally, `System.exit()` is considered harmful, because you may forget that you (or not know that your coworker) had something effective tied to the shutdown event.